# Checkout next button not going to custom step

Tags: checkout, magento2.4.3

I'm using Magento 2.4.3-p1. I have created a custom checkout step according to Magento's tutorial here: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

My step is in between the shipping and payment step. When I go to checkout the shipping step loads fine, but after filling out the address/billing info and select a shipping method my custom step does not load when I click "Next". I'm using the default Luma theme and don't have any modules that do anything on the checkout process.

My code is just a copy/paste from the tutorial (other than vendor and module names) so I'm not sure why it doesn't work. I'm hoping there's something obvious/simple that I'm missing.

`view/frontend/web/js/view/my-step-vew.js`

```
define([
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
], function (ko, Component, _, stepNavigator) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * mystep - is the name of the component's .html template,
     * <Vendor>_<Module>  - is the name of your module directory.
     */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'MyVendor_MyModule/mystep'
        },

        // add here your logic to display step,
        // This is the only difference from the tutorial
        // I changed it to false from true
        isVisible: ko.observable(false),

        /**
         * @returns {*}
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                // step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                'step_code',
                // step alias
                null,
                // step title value
                'Shipping',
                // observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                 * sort order value
                 * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                 * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                 * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                 */
                15
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout steps
         * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
         * for switching to your custom step
         * When the user navigates to the custom step via url anchor or back button we_must show step manually here
         */
        navigate: function () {
            this.isVisible(true);
        },

        /**
         * @returns void
         */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            stepNavigator.next();
        }
    });
});
```

`view/frontend/web/template/mystep.html`

```
<!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="step_code" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: 'Step Title'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

`view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="my-new-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule/js/view/my-step-view</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`view/frontend/base/requirejs-config.js`

```
var config = {
    'config': {
        'mixins': {
           'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment': {
               'Vendor_Module/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin': true
           }
       }
    }
};
```

`view/web/js/view/shipping-payment-mixin.js`

```
define([
    'ko'
], function (ko) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {

        initialize: function () {
            // set visible to be initially false to have your step show first
            this.visible = ko.observable(false);
            this._super();

            return this;
        }
    };

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that one of my third party modules was the issue this whole time. Disabled it and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

can you point out what all 3rd party modules you disabled.